# how to write the character value from structure into the serial interface and convert into integer value?

Tags: c, arrays, serialization, struct, char

```
struct MemoryTag1;

typedef struct MemoryTag1{
    char a[8]= {'+','0','2','6','.','5','EA','\r'}; // setpoint temperature value
    char b[8]= {'-','0','2','4','.','5','EB','\r'};
    char c[6]= {'+','0','2','0','EC','\r'};
    }Memory1;
```

// This is a message structure which I want to transfer over the serial interface (RS232) and later convert into integer value. please guide me in this.

Answer (score 0):

you can not declare struct in C in this way:

it should be

```
typedef struct MemoryTag1{
    char a[9];
    char b[9];
    char c[7];
    }Memory1;
```

you can set value in the declaration of an object of this structure:

```
Memory1 test = {
    {'+','0','2','6','.','5','E','A','\r'},
    {'-','0','2','4','.','5','E','B','\r'},
    {'+','0','2','0','E','C','\r'}
};
```

If you use this bloc in each initiation of a `Memory1` object so you can use macro to make it easier:

```
#define INIT_MEMORYTAG1 {\
    {'+','0','2','6','.','5','E','A','\r'},\
    {'-','0','2','4','.','5','E','B','\r'},\
    {'+','0','2','0','EC','\r'}\
}
```

and then in your declaration of a `Memory1` object:

```
Memory1 test = INIT_MEMORYTAG1;
```

**BTW:** You can not put `'EA'`, `'EB'`, `'EC'` like a 1 charachter you have to separate them to:
`'E','A'`, `'E','B'`, `'E','C'` and so you have to update your char array sizes in the struct definition

Comment: You also need to fix the `EA`, `EB`, `EC` characters and increase the array sizes.

Comment: I did not remark that. he should separate these charachters in different charachters

Comment: how to interpret this message structure as +026.5 as temperature value, EA as equipment A ?

Answer (score 0):

That is really not C syntax.

You can't have initializers in declarations of types, that doesn't have any meaning.

You need to do it like this, to build the message:

```
 typedef struct {
   char a[10];
   char b[10];
   char c[8];
 } Memory1;

 int main(void)
 {
   Memory1 m1;

   strcpy(m1.a, "+026.5EA\r");
   strcpy(m1.b, "-024.5EB\r");
   strcpy(m1.c, "+020EC\r");
   return 0;
 }
```

Note that the above will build proper C strings in the fields of the message, i.e. there will be 0-characters acting as terminators. The sizes were too small, so I changed that.

It's trivial to ignore the terminator characters if you need to send this over some format that doesn't allow them; send each field separately.

Converting one of the fields back into integers could be done using `sscanf()`, for instance.

Comment: you can not use strcpy, and string. the data defined by the OP does not contain null charachter at the end

Comment: how to interpret this message structure as +026.5 as temperature value, EA as equipment A ??

Comment: @MOHAMED Sure we can use a string, as I said it then depends on how the data is transmitted. No requirement to include the `'0'` when sending this (or writing to file, or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a bit off - try this:

```
// declare Memory1 struct type to hold data

typedef struct MemoryTag1 {
    char a[9]; // setpoint temperature value
    char b[9];
    char c[7];
} Memory1;

// allocate and initialise a Memory1 struct

Memory1 m = { {'+','0','2','6','.','5','E','A','\r'},
              {'-','0','2','4','.','5','E','B','\r'},
              {'+','0','2','0','E','C','\r'} };
```

Answer (score 0):

Really, to be honest, I'd prefer more information. But it doesn't really matter. It only affects the method of output. If you were running this on an arduino, for instance, you could output to the serial ports as easily as:

```
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.write('a');
```

etc, etc

As others have mentioned, there are situations in which you'd be better off using null-terminated strings. If however, you had a particular reason to do so, then I suppose you *could*;

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct memoryTag1_t
{
    char a[9]; // setpoint temperature value
    char b[9];
    char c[7];
} *pMemoryTag1_t;

typedef struct memoryTag2_t
{
    char a[10]; // setpoint temperature value
    char b[10];
    char c[8];
} *pMemoryTag2_t;


void displayField1(char *field, int len)
{
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if (i!=0) printf(",");
        printf("%c", field[i]);
    }printf("\n");
}

void displayField2(char *field)
{
    bool firstDone = false;
    while (*field)
    {
        if (firstDone)
            printf(",");
        else
            firstDone = true;
        printf("%c", *field++);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    memoryTag1_t myMem1 =
        {
            {'+','0','2','6','.','5','E','A','\r'},
            {'-','0','2','4','.','5','E','B','\r'},
            {'+','0','2','0','E','C','\r'}
        };

    memoryTag2_t myMem2 =
        {
            "+026.5EA\r",
            "-024.5EB\r",
            "+020EC\r"
        };

    displayField1(myMem1.a, sizeof(myMem1.a));
    displayField1(myMem1.b, sizeof(myMem1.b));
    displayField1(myMem1.c, sizeof(myMem1.c));

    displayField2(myMem2.a);
    displayField2(myMem2.b);
    displayField2(myMem2.c);
}
```

**Output:**
(Don't forget there's a \r printed 'after' the last comma in each line)

```
+,0,2,6,.,5,E,A,
-,0,2,4,.,5,E,B,
+,0,2,0,E,C,
+,0,2,6,.,5,E,A,
-,0,2,4,.,5,E,B,
+,0,2,0,E,C,
```

Comment: you are specifying this and not using anywhere : *pMemoryTag2_t;        what is the use of it ??

Comment: True. I hadn't noticed, it's become habit. Basically, pMemoryTag2_t is a type which is a pointer to a memoryTag_2. By making the fact that it's a pointer part of the type-name, it can remove confusion. The Windows API does this commonly. I.e char and pchar. CHAR and PCHAR - a char and a char pointer. It also makes it easier(to look at and quickly understand) when passing a pointer as a reference.

Comment: If I want to send that data over the serial interface then serial.write(a);  serial write(b); serial write (c);

Comment: how to send only char a[] over the interface ??

Comment: I'll expand a little on the _first sentence of my answer_ - without knowing which OS and/or system you're using, you'll not get an answer. As I demonstrated, sending them out the serial port is trivial with Arduino. But to answer _your_ question - I don't know, never needed to. Just google "using COM ports windows c/c++" or linux if that's your system, or if the hardware isn't x86, then search for the same thing, albeit for the platform you do have. You'd probably find some code in a "serial-port monitor" project on source-forge or github or google code. The answer awaits you.... :)